# MVC model properties and multiple forms on one view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have a general question, but something that is killing me, and once explained, will help a lot. I am wondering how the models are preserved in a view. Basically, if I have three different forms on one view, and they all use the same model, but are updating different properties, do they all have the same model state when each form is submitted to its own controller action? Or, if a property of a model is not stored somewhere on page after rendering, does it get lost and not preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate post actions for each form i.e change the forms action so that the state for the model is different. When you post a form and capture the model in controller the state for each will be different .

So steps are:

- Create separate post actions for each form in the controller.
- Change the form's action parameter to the one you created in the controller.
- You can use the common model now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there are not enough properties stored on the page itself for ASP.NET MVC to be able to determine which model class to use and reconstruct it, it will be "lost" (lost in the sense that it will not re-build your model object on postback; but you can still rebuild it manually using the `FormCollection`).

Default model binding works by simply assigning HTML `form` values to the corresponding properties of the model object. *(This isn't absolutely true; for example, you can write a custom model binder, or take other approaches, but for the purpose of what you're asking (default MVC model binding) - it is a HTML form field <-> model property relationship.)*

This is the reason why `hidden` HTML `input` fields are often used to preserve model properties which are not user-editable.